# Missing point in references

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, ref

My question is regarding the object references. My tables and figures are numbered like:

```
figure:1.2.:
table:1.3.1.:
```

But when I try to reference these objects with:

```
\ref{fig:example}
\ref{tab:example}
```

the result does not look correct. The final dot "**.**" is missing, i.e., the reference to the figure looks like `1.2` and not like `1.2.`.

I include pictures like:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=90mm,scale=0.25]{visio/osi}
 \end{center}
 \caption{that's a nice picture}
 \label{fig:osi-model}
\end{figure}
```

Does anybody have an idea what I have to change?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Ideas? Many. Suggestion? None. There is no way for us to tell you what to do as you haven't shared any code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is the correct behavior for LaTeX, by default; if you want to redefine the way your references appear, there are plenty of sources around which will explain it.  Redefining `\thefigure` is where you want to start; e.g., `\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\thefigure.}`.

Comment: If you do as you wish, you'll end up with two dots when you reference at the end of a sentence, but this surely can't be correct?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I did not know, that this is the correct behavior for LaTeX.